# How to share image intent with viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to develop an application, where I need to be able to `share image` from `ImageView in ViewPager` when user `press on Share Button`.

**My problem:**

- when I`press on Share Button` the `ImageView` cache the next `Image` not the current .

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      private ViewPager pager;
         private ImageView Imgv;

  `@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
      final Integer[] imageUrls={
          R.drawable.img1 , R.drawable.img2 , R.drawable.img3 , R.drawable.img4
      };
      pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(imageUrls));

      Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
      share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              Imgv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
              Bitmap icon = Imgv.getDrawingCache();
              ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
              File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
              try {
                  file.createNewFile();
                  FileOutputStream  fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                  fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
              } catch (IOException e) {                       
                      e.printStackTrace();
              }

              Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
              Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg");
              shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
              shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
              startActivity(shareIntent);
          }
      });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
      return true;
  }
  private class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

      private LayoutInflater inflater;
      private Integer[] fimg;

      public MyAdapter(Integer[] fimg ) {
          this.fimg=fimg;

          inflater = getLayoutInflater();

      }

      @Override
      public Object instantiateItem(View collection,  int position  ) {


          final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imgview, null);

         Imgv =  (ImageView)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.full_image_view); 





          Imgv.setBackgroundResource(fimg[position]);








           ((ViewPager) collection).addView(imageLayout ,0);


             return imageLayout;  

         }  




      @Override
      public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return super.getItemPosition(object);
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return fimg.length;
      }
      @Override
      public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
          ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
      } 
      @Override
      public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return view==((View)object);
      }

        @Override  
        public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader loader) {}  

        @Override  
        public Parcelable saveState() {  
            return null;  
        }  
        @Override
          public void startUpdate(View container) {
          }
        @Override
          public void finishUpdate(View container) {

          }`

  }

  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you think that Imgv is ImageView from current visible page in ViewPager. But it isnt. In your case Imgv is ImageView from the last inflated page, but not the current visible page.

I suggest you to add tag to ImageView:

```
Imgv.setBackgroundResource(fimg[position]);
Imgv.setTag(position);  // add this line
```

Then you can find your ImageView by tag:

```
ImageView Imgv = (ImageView)pager.findViewWithTag(pager.getCurrentItem());
Imgv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
...
```

Comment: Thank You Leonidas .. This is a simplest Solution . i am so happy for your reply ..

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using the drawing cache which may sometimes mean a downscaled image, I'd check out the onPageSelected() event of the [ViewPager onPageChange listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29).

Save the current index, and create the file to be saved from your original asset.

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest and best way to get the images is by using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem()

This will give you the index of the current page which is nothing but the index of the imageUrls which has the current image.

So get your bitmap from imageUrls using BitmapFactory.

BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageUrls[pager.getCurrentItem()]);